# Mr. President, Magic has returned to our world

Tags: magic, politics

3/19/2022 **CIA official briefing, EXTREMELY URGENT**

---

Mr. President,

Over the past several weeks, it has come to the attention of the CIA and several other global intelligence agencies that certain individuals have been displaying inexplicable paranormal abilities. Observing these individuals has yielded interesting results.

Many of them appear to be as confused as we are, having only just discovered their abilities. A few say they have had these abilities for as long as a half a year, and have honed them through trial and error. There is a third group. At least half a dozen of the observed claim to have had their abilities for longer. Substantially longer, in fact. The oldest among them maintains that he was worshiped as a god in Ancient Mesopotamia. While we have been unable to evaluate the truth of their claims, their abilities are indisputable, and are of such a nature that some at the Agency have taken to calling it 'magic'.

The Affected vary widely in ability type and strength. Observations and interviews reveal that there is some kind of semi-hard limit on the strength. Most Affected are relatively weak, even given a great deal of practice and knowledge. One common trait to the weaker Affected is that they tire quickly. One subject quickly knocked herself unconscious due to the strain of lifting a SWAT team van for several seconds. Another (in an attempt to evade a capture team) held the shape of a small dog for a full minute. A third nearly convinced one of our operatives to shoot himself before tiring. This reflects the power level of the middle 30% of Affected we observed.

The abilities of the Affected are channeled through either: a. verbal commands (the most popular option, do not resemble any known language and are rarely shared between Affected), b. hand gestures (occasionally used in addition to verbal commands, not necessarily hands), or c. written runes. Denied of these, the Affected find it difficult if not impossible to use their abilities.

While the most powerful Affected are not necessarily ancient, the ancient Affected all appear to be extremely powerful. All attempts to capture the ancient Affected were terminated with laughable (occasionally contemptuous) ease. We were only able to interview two of them, who volunteered. If they are to be believed, magic was intentionally eliminated from the world roughly three thousand years ago. The Affected who survived either went dormant or had previously altered themselves to become immortal. One of the ancient interviewees spoke very poor English and was having significant difficulty adapting to the modern world.

Since 'magic' has returned to this world very recently (at most a year ago), few organizations of Affected have been able to form. The most common form of organization is created when a small group of very confused Affected seek each other out over the internet and begin to trade discoveries. Other organizations we have observed include: a. 'the Keepers', a group of several dozen moderately accomplished Affected who seek out lost artifacts from the ancient age of magic, and b. an as yet nameless group of Affected environmentalists who use their abilities to replenish natural areas. We note with some distress that the Mafia and the Zetas drug cartel have begun to develop sub-organizations of the Affected.

Finally, a note on the abilities we have observed more than once:
Precognition, teleportation, shapeshifting, mind control, healing, gravity manipulation, telekinesis, transmutation, and memory erasure.

Mr. President, what the hell do we do about this? Do we alert the public? start a witch hunt (no pun intended)? The CIA awaits your instruction.

---

When answering, please state your intention before your course of action. Bonus points if you can answer from the perspective of multiple world leaders. #Resurgence

Comment: If the people in question are Americans or this event is happening on US soil, then this briefing would be coming from the FBI or homeland security.  CIA  deals with foreign intelligence gathering not domestic.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the [SCP Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCP_Foundation).

Comment: I apologize Anketam, I was not aware.

Comment: 2022 is 5 years from now...then it's pretty safe to think that the answer from POTUS will be "Blame Obama", then a few statements contradicting each others, then some confused blabbering.

Comment: @Megalonychidae no need to apologize.  It is important factor though with answering this question though.  If the people are US citizens or on US soil they get a lot more legal protection then if they are a foreigner on foreign soil, and thus directly impact what the president is authorized to order.

Comment: Isn't this pretty much the storyline of X-Men? "OMG People with strange powers!"

Comment: I would recommend you to read the _Shadowrun_ series of RPG books. The setting has a similar premise of magic coming back and doing all sorts of weird things to people, and could be an excellent starting point for inspiration.

Comment: "Mr. President, what the hell do we do about this?" If you're asking this now, the answer will probably be "nuke 'em!"

Comment: I'm voting to close this post since it's asking about the decisions of an individual in a world which under current rules is too story based for this site.

Comment: @sphennings The individual is not a true character but a stand-in for the answerer. The question is just creative phrasing of "what should the government do" which is generally an allowed form. I wouldn't give it any awards for clarity but closure of this five-year-old question just seems non-productive to me.

Comment: @KeizerHarm That's not what it says in the help center "If on the other hand you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site," https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. When an old question becomes active again, if under current rules it does not meet site standards, it should be closed to not confuse new members to current site policy.

Comment: @sphennings The government is not just any organisation, it is a system of rules for a country and its executioners. Drafting rules is on-topic.

Comment: @KeizerHarm It depends on specifics of the question. Asking "What rules should be drafted?" is the same as asking "What should be done?" which is off topic as described above.

Comment: @sphennings Would you still VTC if the question explicitly included more objective goals, such as maintaining rule of law and minimising the possibility of rebellion; or is any question about theoretical governments or government actions off-topic?

Comment: @KeizerHarm Probably since you'd still be asking "What should my character or organization do in this situation" add all the criteria you want and you won't change the core ask, which is where the issue resides. If you reframe the question to ask "Would X be likely to preserve the rule of law?" then sure ask away. But the open ended "What do?" isn't a good fit for the site.

Comment: Separate from the issue of on-topicness, it occurs to me on rereading the question that if this has been going on for several weeks, the president would already have been briefed about it.

Comment: @sphennings That just makes every "best way to X" off-topic, including those that make perfect specifications of goals and limitations. I cannot agree with that. Consider close-voting everything on this query: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=title%3abest

Comment: @KeizerHarm If you want to have a general discussion of site policy I suggest you post a question on meta.

Comment: @sphennings Ok, never mind. This site riles me up sometimes.

Answer (score 20):

Mr. Director,

**First of all:** Regardless of whatever strange abilities they may possess, those who are American citizens are to be given their full rights as American citizens. If they have committed crimes, they should be arrested (if possible) and given due process. If they have not committed crimes, they are **not** to be harassed. While I appreciate the enhanced security risk that rogue "magic" users pose, a blanket policy of detaining everybody with these abilities is both illegal and un-American. I expect your agents to follow this order effective immediately.

Furthermore, I am instructing all U.S. intelligence agencies and all branches of the military to begin an active recruitment campaign among these individuals. As with any pool of talent, the more of them we have on our side, the better. We need to recruit them before criminal organizations or foreign powers do. You will, of course, conduct especially thorough investigations into recruits' backgrounds and other ties before granting security clearances.

I want a full report on the numbers and relative strength of these individuals in other countries, how other governments are reacting, and the degree to which criminal organizations' recruitment efforts are succeeding.

Continue monitoring any online communities to the fullest legal extent, so that we can be aware of any hostile groups taking shape.

Finally, be especially careful dealing with the highly powerful individuals. I am disturbed that attempts have been made to capture some of them, no doubt provoking fear and animosity toward the U.S. government. Your agents are henceforth to take a conciliatory approach at all times, unless to do so would endanger the lives of civilians. We do not need such powerful people as enemies. If they wish to be left alone, and if they are not harming anyone, leave them alone. At the same time, continue your efforts to establish friendly communication and learn more about this phenomenon. You have my authorization to extend the aid of the U.S. government (including English lessons and job training) to any "ancient" individuals who need help assimilating into American society.

(There is no need to announce anything to the public; due to this morning's incident in San Antonio, all major news networks are running a lead story on the phenomenon as I write this. My aides tell me that #magicisreal has become a trending topic on Twitter. I will be taking a call from our NATO allies this evening to discuss the matter. Depending on public reaction, I may address the nation within the next few days. We must live up to America's reputation by reacting in a spirit of welcome, not of fear.)

President _________
The White House
March 19, 2022

Comment: Ha! If only this was actually how a president would react! We can still dream though, perhaps by 2022... +1

Comment: Ho boy, this will not go over well with the "law and order" crowd.

Comment: @AngelPray Welcome to 2022

Comment: @ReinstateMonica3167040 Welcome to 2022, indeed! Sadly the now 5 year old dream still hasn't come true. Perhaps it will 5 years from now. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Reallisticaly?

We must gather them all and study their superpowers! Specifically, we MUST do it before someone else can. Let's invest half of our budget for pensions, education and healthcare just to fund a new investigation section of DARPA to deal with these subjects - we'll deal with the protests later, invent a new enemy or start a war, I'll think about it after lunch.

The "Affected" must be located and caged a.s.a.p. and studies on their abilities should commence immediately. Our first priority would be weaponizable abilities, and mind control or memory erasure - this one would be of great use against the press and civil rights lawyers, since we officially don't support this nor do that kind of things to our people.

Strategies and plans to deal with the ancients must be prepared and deployed immediately. If they are too powerful to be confronted, we will be forced to kill them from beyond visual range while reducing collateral damage as much as possible. The acquisition of these new capabilities for our country should take precedence over any other considerations.

Answer (score 1):

**Tldr: I feel the question is a bit vague if it doesn't mention their exact superpowers. Understanding their powers and intentions is the first rational objective that comes to mind.**

**Firstly we have to determine what the Affected want.** If they just have ordinary human desires and want to lead a life within current rules, then it makes sense to make allies with them as soon as possible.

If possible, they will have to be surveiled and studied, before contact is made. **They will be granted asylum in our country if they are willing to go through a series of physical and psychological tests that will establish trust between us and assure us that the Affected will not break our law.** If they want any modifications to the law, or any other requests, they may do so. Of we feel they are particularly threatening, we may have to carefully make requests in these contracts as well as establish working fail-safes.

If however, some of them do wish to actively​ break current rules or ally with organisations working against our country, or else participate in any activity that we deem harmful to us or to their minds, then we will have to take a cautious stand on the same. We could end up with anything from a new international cold war to an Affected issuing ultimatums to the globe, etc. etc. It will be best to make our intentions clear to them to avoid such a situation.

**Actions will be taken largely on the basis of intel gathered**, whether it is new contracts or a quarantine or even an elimination of an Affected. Action will depend on the nature of the threats they possess and the abilities we know they possess. It would be unwise to engage in combat without knowing their abilities. Some sacrifices might have to be made for the larger good, both on our part as on theirs.

Comment: I'm not sure you read the question very carefully. The Affected are not a monolithic group, and they are about as disorganized as it is possible to be. They are just as confused, if not more confused than we are. And exact abilities *are* mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

CIA: take this course of action immediately, find and contain all of the Affected, we will build a large compound, maybe in Russia or Canada, those huge empty places and with the help of governments around the world we will restrain the Affected.  The only hard part are the ancient Affected, but they're good at being quiet.  The only thing we really don't want is a witch hunt, it'll ruin modern day society.

Sincerely Mr. President.

Comment: Um Mr President, we do not have a good working relationship with Russia, you know that cold war and all, it is very doubtful they would help us with this, not to mention do we really want to be trusting Russia with people that have super powers?

Comment: Unfortunately this is likely to be impossible. There are a thousand ways in which even a moderately powerful Affected could escape in days. Also, is it really wise to give that many powerful people reason to hate America and then enclose them in a relatively small space? The phrase "angry tornado in a can" comes to mind.

Answer (score -2):

Mr. Director

I regret to inform you that I, the new leader of the Grand Old Party, have overthrown president DLosc due to excessive woke-ness in dealing with this new threat. You now answer to me; if you are unhappy about this, I'll happily accept your resignation.

Those orders you recieved yesterday? Toss them in the trash. Your new orders are to round up all of these witches and warlocks, the only exception being those in the top 0.1%. Those plutocrats work hard to keep america turning and put a stop to socialism, we are NOT going to let these socialist magic-users take away their hard-earned right to their piles of gold.

If anyone objects to this, lock them up too. Oh, and those 'powerful' magic users? Use any means at your disposal to kill them, nukes included. It is better to murder 5 million innocents than let a single socialist go free.

-(insert bigoted conservative wannabe-tyrants' name here)

Comment: There's a nub of a good realpolitik-focused answer here (I agree that my answer is a *touch* optimistic), but a lot of it reads as a political rant. I don't think anybody would actually say "It is better to murder 5 million innocents," regardless of how much they hate the opposite ideology.

Comment: It's an exaggeration, yes, but there are some conservatives who are legitimately on the side of not reversing death sentences given to OBVIOUSLY and PROVEABLY innocent people out of concern for 'the integrity of our justice system'. There are conservatives who'd allow innocents to die if it meant somebody guilty died with those innocents, though they'd likely never admit it out loud and I am depicting a hyper-exaggeration of that attitude here.